# Why can't I deserialize this JSON with JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json

**Background**

So I have decided to start using JSON instead of XML for some C# programs. Naturally, the first thing I found was Newtonsoft's JSON.NET. This seems like a reasonable thing to be using for some JSON parsing in the .NET world, and everyone has suggested it over the built-in serializer that Microsoft offers. So that is what I have decided to use. So far, I have not been able to de-serialize anything but the very trivial examples such as... [This one here.](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm)

I am trying to de-serialize the following JSON into a meaningful object that I can use for my program, however the application crashes everytime I try to do so. I get a very vague explanation of what happened in the exception-message. I don't get a line-number or anything, just says...

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'JsonTest.testObjects' because the type
>   requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.

Maybe it's saying there is a problem with my first object? I am not using any array here until I get into the sub-classes, not really sure what's going on here.

```
{
    "name":"myTest",
    "testObjects":[
        "testObject":
            "name":"Operator Tests",
            "index":1,
            "description":"Test out the operator interface.",
            "SubTests":[
                "SubTest":
                    "name":"Display Test",
                    "index":4,
                    "description":"Testing for display faults.",
                    "Steps":[
                        "Step":
                            "name":"Configuration #1",
                            "Parameters":[
                                "Mode-A",
                                "Unit #1"
                            ],
                        "Step":
                            "name":"Configuration #2",
                            "Parameters":[
                                "Mode-B",
                                "Unit #1"
                            ],
                        "Step":
                            "name":"Configuration #3",
                            "Parameters":[
                                "Mode-C",
                                "Unit #1"
                            ]
                    ]
            ]
    ]
}
```

Alright, and then here is the de-serialization code.

```
    Test newTest = null;
    String testData = String.Empty;

    // read the file
    testData = File.ReadAllText("Test.json");

    // de-serialize the JSON
    newTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(testData);
```

Then, here is the `Test` class that is getting de-serialized. The `Test` object is the object that houses all of the `testObjects`. I will initially not provide information about the sub-classes until explicitly asked to do so, as I believe the problem may be somewhere with my JSON to begin with. I will provide as much detail as anyone asks me for, just ask!

**Question**

Why won't this serialize, what is this exception/message actually telling me?

Comment: This is not legal Json: `testObject": "name":"Operator Tests",`, is the data missing som braces? You've indented the information after `testObject, but it is not a legal object.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, not that I'm aware of. There is... 1 for each of the 3 `Step`. 1 for `Steps`. 1 for `SubTests`. 1 for `testObjects`... So, no?

Comment: Yeah, that ain't json.  That's json-like pseudomarkup

Comment: You don't have valid JSON. Plug it into [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and you'll see. And if you're having trouble deserializing into a specific type, you need to include that type in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating C# classes from JSON try using: http://json2csharp.com/

From **valid** JSON it generates:

```
public class Step
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class SubTest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}

public class TestObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<SubTest> SubTests { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<TestObject> testObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Helpful, do I need to mark the elements with [JsonProperty()]?

Comment: i would recommend you to only mark elements, which you want to ignore with [ScriptIgnore]. You only need JsonProperty if you want to name your properties differently in json vs c#. - And i would not recommend that :)

Comment: So I can leave it just how you have it there, and it should work? I am so used to the XML-world.

Comment: Well mostly, give the classes some self-explanatory names (I assume you use example-code here)

Answer (score 7):

Not legal JSON: use http://jsonlint.com/

```
{
    "name": "myTest",
    "testObjects": [
        "testObject":
        "name": "Operator Tests",
        "index": 1,
```

testObjects is an array, but you specify key value pairs in it. So the contents should be a object, or a list of objects.

I think you want something like this:

```
{
    "name":"myTest",
    "testObjects":[
        {
            "name":"Operator Tests",
            "index":1,
            "description":"Test out the operator interface.",
            "SubTests":[
                {
                    "name":"Display Test",
                    "index":4,
                    "description":"Testing for display faults.",
                    "Steps":[
                        {
                            "name":"Configuration #1",
                            "Parameters":[
                                "Mode-A",
                                "Unit #1"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Configuration #2",
                            "Parameters":[
                                "Mode-B",
                                "Unit #1"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Configuration #3",
                            "Parameters":[
                                "Mode-C",
                                "Unit #1"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Will I need an intermediate class for the testObjects, or can I do it as a IList<testObject> ?

Comment: Can you provide the corresponding C# code for the top-level class? I still get the same exception.

Comment: For parsing I would suggest making a different question on StackOverflow with the code used.